# How to bind images from list of images in data template?

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.forms, datatemplateselector, itemtemplateselector

I've created a template selector and I'm using ffimage for caching the images. The model which is bind to the listView has a list of image urls which I need to bind to the image source. I'm binding the images as

```
postImage.SetBinding(CachedImage.SourceProperty, new Binding("image_url[0].media_url"));
```

Sometimes this works and sometimes the error comes as TargetInvocationException and I'm not able to find out, where this exception is coming but when I delete the bindings then the error goes away.

Comment: Just an idea but why dont you create an attribute imagesource as string in your object and assign values?

Comment: can you paste the entire stack trace, it should contained more detailed information on what went wrong. Also check the validity of your input data. Could the "image_url" be null in that instance?

Comment: @Mr.Koçak I've also tried to pass the source using object but the problem is coming after I scroll to the list and then the app crashes. It says ArrayOutOfBoundException index 20, 25

Comment: @irreal here is the stack trace
  --- End of managed Java.Lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException stack trace ---
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=20; index=20
at android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.addScrapView(AbsListView.java:7148)
at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5480)
at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4599)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:559)

Comment: @irreal I'm debugging the datatemplateselector and when I'm scrolling for 4 posts the OnSelecteTemplate is called about 5-6 times for every post. I don't know why it calls the template selector so many times and after calling so many times the error comes as ArrayOutOfBounds Exception, index was out of range: index 22, 25 or sometimes the index value comes as 20,20 and it depends how I'm scrolling, slow or faster

Comment: @irreal I've also checked the device log but no luck